# Mock suspend function return null because of different scopes

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to test a ViewModel

```
class ViewModel {
  val data = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
  val api = Api()

  fun loadData(params: Map<String>) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      data = api.fetchData(params) // return null LiveData here
    }
  }
}

class Api {
  suspend fun fetchData(params: Map<String>): LiveData<List<String>>
}
```

And my test code is:

```
fun testFetchData() = runBlockingTest {
  `when`(apiMock.fetchData(mapOf())).thenReturn(MutableLiveData(listOf("a", "b")))
  viewModel.loadData(mapOf())
  assertThat(viewModel.data.value).isEqualTo(listOf("a", "b"))
}
```

I run the test and it crashes because the Api.fetchData() does not return the mocked result - MutableLiveData(listOf("a", "b")) but it returns null. As far as I know, the reason is: the scope of runBlockingTest where I mock the function, and the scope of viewModelScope.launch where the function run is different.

Any suggestion to deal with this situation? better without changing ViewModel code

Comment: Do you use the normal `mockito` version (java based) or `mockito-kotlin`? I am not very familiar with kotlin, but `Api.fetchData()` looks like a `static` function to me, which `mockito` would not be able to mock.

Comment: No it is not a static function. Sorry for the inaccurate code because it is simplified so I can illustrate the issue easier. It turns out the reason is not scope of coroutine but because I mocked the function in wrong way. In fact fetchData receives a map as parameter, and instead of passing anyMap() when mock, I passed mapOf() and it makes the mock failed.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, i believe you should **pass Dispatcher to viewModel** so in your test you can use Dispatcher.undefined..

and use this lib [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)

second, in **mockito** you can use this code when you want to mock suspend
functions :

```
        mockedObject.stub {
            onBlocking { suspendFunction() }.doReturn(true)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn out the reason is because I mocked the wrong way

```
`when`(apiMock.fetchData(mapOf())).thenReturn(MutableLiveData(listOf("a", "b")))`
```

should use anyMap() instead of mapOf():

```
`when`(apiMock.fetchData(anyMap())).thenReturn(MutableLiveData(listOf("a", "b")))
```

Comment: you saved my life with this! How did you find it out that you should use any()? 
Is there any documentation or sample?

Comment: @gts13 mapOf() means you are passing an empty map and anyMap() is an argument matcher used to match any argument which is of type Map